# Checking the UIWebView's URL

Tags: ios, objective-c, url, uiwebview

So I have an image that I would like to hide only if my `UIWebView` is currently on a certain URL. For example, if "example1.com/cheese" was currently being displayed in my `UIWebView`, then I will hide the image. I have no idea how to go about checking to see if a specific URL is loaded in though. I'm trying this:

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request {

    NSString *host = [request.URL host];

    if ([host != isEqualToString:@"example1.com/cheese"]) {
        image.hidden = NO;
    }
    else
        image.hidden = YES;
}
```

My issue lies within my `if` statement. I'm unsure of how to do a "is not equal to this URL". Does anyone know what I need to change or add to fix this?

**Update**: This is the code I'm working with now, the error appearing is `Use of undeclared identifier, host.`:

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request {
    if (![host isEqualToString:@"exampleURL.com/cheese"]) {
        image.hidden = NO;
    } else {
        image.hidden = YES;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is basic Objective-C (really C) syntax:

```
if (![host isEqualToString:@"someURL"]) {
    // doesn't match
} else {
    // does match
}
```

The `!` means "not". It negates the result of the expression. Since `isEqualToString:` returns `YES` if the two strings are equal, the `!` negates it to `NO`. If the two strings are not equal, the `NO` result gets negated to `YES`.

You can also do this:

```
// Hide image if host matches "someURL"
image.hidden = [host isEqualToString:@"someURL"];
```

Comment: Thanks, that helps out a lot! Should I keep the same method name? For some reason it can't find `host` when I load that code into it.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure what you mean. Keep which method name? And what do you mean by "can't find `host` when I load that code into it"?

Comment: Sorry about that, I'm still getting used to the terminology. I just updated my question with the code I'm using and the error that's occurring.

Comment: Your updated code is missing this line: `NSString *host = [request.URL host];`